# New to Ubuntu. Just installed 14.04; am having trouble upgrading to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

I just installed Ubuntu from a purchased thumbdrive and was offered to upgrade to 16.04. So I tried, three times, and I got the error message to free up some space from the previous updates in the "temp folder". I have nothing else on my 350 g / 6 g Ram  disc but Ubuntu that I just installed. I am not sure how to free up that space.Any advice?

Comment: Why not install Ubuntu 16.04 from scratch? It will be much easier.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this (providing your 14.04 is still working) is to download (free) the 16.04 installer, make a bootable thumb drive with it, and make a clean install of 16.04, allowing the installer to partition and format the storage device.

Of course, if you've put any personal files on the machine, you'll want to make backups or copies before you start.

For future reference, the only reason I can see to pay for a DVD or thumb drive copy of Ubuntu is if you anticipate needing to install where you don't have Internet access -- and even then, you can download the installer for free, burn it to the chosen media, and test it before you go off grid.